# How to encrypt data saved in database using php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have to save all data stored in table in encrypted form. In php codeigniter i found encryption library. i am using following code:-

```
 $this->encryption->initialize(
array(
'driver' => 'openssl',
'cipher' => 'aes-256',
'mode' => 'ctr',
'key' => 'CKXH2U9RPY3EFD70TLS1ZG4N8WQBOVI6AMJ5'
)
);

$ciphertext = $this->encryption->encrypt($firstname);
echo $ciphertext;


echo $this->encryption->decrypt($ciphertext);
```

Challenge here is even if $firstname is 10 character , encrypted text is random and also the length vary each and everytime.

Is there any way i can restrict length of encrypted text and encrypted text be similar everytime.

Comment: Any encryption algorithm where the cleartext and ciphertext for any given string are the same length is not worth its salt.

Comment: atleast not of same length but some thing of fixed length would be great, right now for 10 character it is converting into 140 character cipher text . Is there any way else i can achieve this?

Comment: did you try md5 or sh1 sh256 functions and not using built in function?

Comment: built function of mysql or php ?

Comment: php. i know md5 IS NOT ENCRYPTION function. just i wonder if you want to encrypt something like first name why not using hash functions. at lease they give you fixed length string